# why not display in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

Item's Path doesn't display in jsp page,I want to export this sentence   ${pageContext.request.contextPath}

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
        <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
        <c:set var="basePath" scope="request">${pageContext.request.contextPath}</c:set>    
        <%
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-catch");
            response.setHeader("Pragma","no-catch");
            response.setDateHeader("Expires",0);
            String a=request.getContextPath();
            System.out.println(a);
             %>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <title>code-serv-web</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>code-serv-web</h1>
            <button id="but">点击</button>

        </body>

    </html>
```

why not display in jsp page  ${pageContext.request.contextPath}

Comment: EL expressions ${} doesn't run in a plain HTML file. It runs in JSP pages.

Comment: try `<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

The El expression should be writen in JSP pages.

${pageContext. Request. ContextPath} is through the get method to get samples, first pageContext. GetRequest () to get it, and then call it getContextPath method
< % % > you have to use pageContext. GetRequest (), the point must not come out, and it doesn't have this property.
The role is to remove the deployed application name so that the path is correct regardless of how it is deployed.

The El expression method: ${pageContext. Request. ContextPath}

The JSP is written in: < % = request.getcontextpath () % >

Answer (score 0):

EL expressions `${}` can be run in JSP files not HTML files.

You have two solutions in your case

Rename your file from `filename.html` to `filename.jsp`

or

Add mapping to your web.xml file

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```